# Mongoose not creating or storing data in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

When I do `mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://username:<my password>@bot.scv9.mongodb.net/test')` it connects but doesn’t create or store anything in the database

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const mongoPath  = 'mongodb+srv://username:<password>@bot.scv9j.mongodb.net/test'

module.exports = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(mongoPath, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  return mongoose
}

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let Schema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    guildid: String,
    guildname: String,
    logchannelid: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Guild', Schema)


db.findOne({ guildid: message.guild.id, user: user.user.id}, async(err, data) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!data) {
                data = new db({
                    guildid: message.guild.id,
                    user : user.user.id,
                    content : [
                        {
                            moderator : message.author.id,
                            reason : reason
                        }
                    ]
                })
            } else {
                const obj = {
                    moderator: message.author.id,
                    reason : reason
                }
                data.content.push(obj)
            }
            data.save()
        });
```

I want it to create the database and then store the data inside it. This is the code Im using and I tried everything that I know of but it still doesn't work.

Node: 12.19.0
Mongoose: 5.10.16
MongoDB: 4.4

Comment: How do you store the data into DB?

Comment: @Minsky I had the await but it didn’t work so I tried removing it and it still doesn’t work.

Comment: I mean: You are trying to store data somewhere into the code, isn't it? So, where (what line) are you saving the data and why is not stored? What error is thrown or what happens? Or the problem is you don't know how to save the data?

Comment: @itsJava add `await` and console log result after calling

Comment: @Minsky alright

Comment: @Minsky it successfully connects

Comment: Alright. Where does `db` in `db.findOne` comes from? as it is, it's undefined. Remove the comments you don't need, please.

Comment: @Minsky oh right! db requires the warns schema

Comment: @Minsky is this wrong?